# HMAC verification API in javascript

Tags: javascript, hmac

I am successfully implemented HMAC verification from the backend but would like to offer JSONP support.  Since I dont want the client to know about the secret key, what is the best way to take advantage of HMAC and make calls from the client?

Comment: Please provide much more information.  What are you trying to verify? What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: I want to make sure that the client getting the data is valid, not an open ended api.  The backend verifies the request by creating a signature from the secret key.  But on the client I cant do this.

Comment: You cannot prevent an attacker from pretending to be your client.  Period.

Answer (score 3):

If the attacker knows the secret key then he will always be able to generate a valid HMAC.  An attacker will be able to obtain this HMAC value by [looking at the traffic](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) or [by modifying the JavaScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).  A JavaScript debugger like firebug could also be used.

In short, this security feature doesn't exist anywhere because its completely and totally worthless.   It sounds like you are very carefully implementing a [CWE-602](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html) violation.

Trusting the client is the worst mistake you could make.  The very foundation of modern web application security is about defending the server from the client.  I think you have a lot to learn.

Comment: I didn't say I was doing it.  I was asking what is a good way to do this from the client.

Comment: @Mike Flynn  then you should probably remove the security tag,  because this is not a security feature.